# How can I get round corners on a LinearLayout in Xamarin Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-linearlayout

I'd like to know how to round the corners of my Xamarin Android Linear Layout. I have the following xml layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_green_dark">

  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv1"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:text="S"
    android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    />
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:text="S"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

and a **View** created in the following manner:

```
public void CreateFloatingWindow()
{
    windowManager = GetSystemService(WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.From(ApplicationContext);
    floatView = mLayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.floatview, null);

    // set LayoutParam
    layoutParams = new WindowManagerLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.Width = 400;
    layoutParams.Height = 200;

    layoutParams.X = 210;
    layoutParams.Y = 300;

    if ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 26)
    {
        layoutParams.Type = WindowManagerTypes.ApplicationOverlay;
    }
    else
    {
        layoutParams.Type = WindowManagerTypes.Phone;
    }

    layoutParams.Flags = WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal;
    layoutParams.Flags = WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable;

    //set round corners
    GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
    shape.SetCornerRadius(CORNER_RADIUS);
    floatView.SetBackground(shape);

    windowManager.AddView(floatView, layoutParams);

}
```

The result I end up with this as below. The corners of the inner shape are rounded but outside the corners is a **black** background.

[image]

How can I make the the black corners **transparent**. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Tried again with **layout_bg.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#00FFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BC76" />
    <corners android:radius="40dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_bg">
...
```

The new shape's green stroke and cyan background are coming through, but the corners are still black.

**UPDATE 2**

I tried setting

```
android:alpha="0.1"
```

but that only makes the image and text controls transparent, not the background itself. The background remains black.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=linearlayout+rounded+corners+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Hi Jason, just followed that, tried out the first answer. It's still black in the corners. Please see **UPDATE** above.

Comment: are you using as root xml or are you inflation this into another one??

Comment: Hi Tanishq, I looked in the debugger for the parent of floatView. It is: ``floatView.Parent {android.view.ViewRootImpl@8b82cc4} Android.Views.IViewParentInvoker``

Comment: Also, as per the code above, the assigned root is null: ``floatView = mLayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.floatview, null);``

Answer (score 0):

I have added some code snippet and output image as you stated above in your doubt/Issue/Question

Below the Main xml file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
   
    android:background="@drawable/temp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:text="S"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:text="S"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here the drawable for the require shape

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:topRightRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="20dp" />
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

</shape>
```

You can customise the corner radius according to your need
[image: Here Your required output]

You can align the view according to you need...I hope this will work for you
Thankyou in Advance!!

Comment: I tried this and still black corners. Strange thing is, even if I set ``android:background="@android:color/transparent"``, the LinearLayout background is still black, so it looks like something is underneath the layout.

Comment: At design time the entire screen is black (just as yours is white), and at runtime the corners only are black.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay in the background created by the **windowManager**.

To solve it I changed the **WindowManagerLayoutParams** as follows and it worked fine:

```
// set LayoutParams
WindowManagerTypes type = ((int)Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= 26 /*Build.VERSION_CODES.O*/) ? WindowManagerTypes.ApplicationOverlay : WindowManagerTypes.Phone;

layoutParams = new WindowManagerLayoutParams(type, WindowManagerFlags.NotFocusable | WindowManagerFlags.NotTouchModal, 
               Format.Transparent);
```

**Note** I also referenced the answer to this issue when arriving at my solution:
[Android: Transparend background when using WindowManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43764858/android-transparend-background-when-using-windowmanager)

Thanks to all for your help!